# How to use Android applications lacking Application() class?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, android-jetpack

A lot of Google's recent sample Android apps, such as the [Kotlin Sunflower sample for Jetpack](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-sunflower), don't seem to have a file that subclasses the Application() class. They just jump straight into the activities.

Is this the new best practice?

How to you use things like Dagger2 or Koin without overriding onCreate() in the Application class? I'm yet to read a How To for dependency injection that doesn't involve some change to Application.onCreate().

I'm trying to learn Android/Kotlin, and I'm using Google's samples as my guide.

If the answer to the DI question is to add a MyApplication.kt file to a project that lacks one, how do I go about that? Does the AndroidManifest.xml file need changing or anything?

Or should I do it some other way in the JetPack/Architecture Components world?

Apologies if this has been asked and answered elsewhere. I'm very new to this and don't even know the terminology for an app that lacks the MyApplication file, so it's been hard for me to search for.

thanks in advance

John

Comment: You should just ask yourself if you need an application class. Some apps do, some do not. If you don't need it, obviously don't add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A lot of Google's recent sample Android apps, such as the Kotlin Sunflower sample for Jetpack, don't seem to have a file that subclasses the Application() class. They just jump straight into the activities.
>
> Is this the new best practice?

If you don't need an Application class you do not have to have an empty one. It will just use the default `Application` the framework provides.

> How to you use things like Dagger2 or Koin without overriding onCreate() in the Application class? I'm yet to read a How To for dependency injection that doesn't involve some change to Application.onCreate().

Just create an application class.

> I'm trying to learn Android/Kotlin, and I'm using Google's samples as my guide.
>
> If the answer to the DI question is to add a MyApplication.kt file to a project that lacks one, how do I go about that? Does the AndroidManifest.xml file need changing or anything?

You have to add `android:name="fully.qualified.class.name.of.MyApplication"` to the `<application>` tag in the manifest.

> Or should I do it some other way in the JetPack/Architecture Components world?

Google recommends Dagger2 see https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide

Answer (score 0):

The Application class is used to maintain global state for the lifecycle of the app. Even though you don't extend it, the base implementation is still being used. See [the documentation for Application](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/Application.java) to see what's going on.